# Tensorflow 2.0 list_physical_devices doesn't detect my GPU

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I recently install tensorflow 2.0 on my computer but when I try to run it on my GPU, the function `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')` on Jupyter or Vitual Studio Code it returns me a void array. Do you know why ?

**My set-up :**

Computer : MSI

Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.220GHz

GPU 0 : Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630

GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060

Python : Ananconda 3 with Python 3.7

Tensenflow 2.0 installed with `pip install tensorflow`

**My test code :**

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(physical_devices)
if physical_devices:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Did you try "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu" or just remove tensorflow and then installing "tensorflow-gpu" ?

Answer (score 8):

Most of the answers are outdated. Modern versions of `tensorflow` include `tensorflow-gpu`. It is not possible to install this last one using `pip` any longer.

Run the following script to check your available devices:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]

print(get_available_devices())

# Your output is probably something like ['/device:CPU:0']
# It should be ['/device:CPU:0', '/device:GPU:0']
```

If you don't see the GPU follow these steps:

1. Update your NVIDIA graphics cards from here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
2. Discover which CUDA version you need. This is told by the error message when running your script that you expect to run in GPU. For example, for my NVIDIA RTX 2060 Super, I get `2021-01-06 12:14:56.670596: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60]  Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found` Therefore I need CUDA version 11. This step is very important, you *must* download a compatible version.
3. Download and install the CUDA Toolkit from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive, either choose the version you need, as discovered in the previous step, or download the latest one (version 12 at the time of this writing).
4. Install Zlib and cuDNN as explained here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows
5. Run the initial script at the top and you should now see something like:

[image]

*Tip: Make sure to restart after each driver update or software installation from the previous steps, just in case.*

Afterwards, all computations you do should use GPU by default. You can check this by looking at the GPU usage of the Taskbar.

### Useful resources:

- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1433/how-to-fix-tensorflow-warning-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64-110dll-dlerror-cudart64-110dll-not-found
- https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section for the benefit of the community.

Instead of `pip install tensorflow`, you can try `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` or just remove `tensorflow` and then `installing "tensorflow-gpu` will resolves your issue.

After installation of Tensorflow GPU, you can check GPU as below

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(physical_devices)
if physical_devices:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Comment: Tried to do it in 2023, on `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, got error `The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed! Please install "tensorflow" instead.`

Answer (score 3):

tensorflow-gpu has been removed, you need to run below command

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

OR

pip install --upgrade tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading simply worked for me.:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

and the device name searched has to be 'XLA_GPU', and does not respond with solo 'GPU' search term. But it also raised another error when setting the memory growth which is not supported by 'XLA' gpus.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing tensorflow with gpu using Conda

First install **anaconda** or **mini-anaconda** on your system and make sure you have set the environment path for `conda` command.

> In below command replace `tensor` with a **environment name** of your choice:

```
conda create -n tensor tensorflow-gpu cudatoolkit=9.0
conda activate tensor
```

> Then update your `tensorflow-gup` package using `pip` and make sure
> your environment is **activated** in **conda**

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

> Verify weather **tensorflow** with **gpu** support is installed
> successfully

```
(tensor) C:\> python

Python 3.8.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 14:38:14) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

The output`[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`  in terminal means we have **successfully** installed tensorflow with gpu.

This answer was taken from [anaconda tensorflow](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) installation link.