# IndexError: list index out of range while trying to use TF-GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, index-error

I'm getting the following error while trying to use TF-GPU for my Face Detection code in Python.

**Error:**
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)

IndexError: list index out of range

[image]

My set-up :

Python: Ananconda 3 with Python 3.7

Tensorflow-GPU 2.1 installed with pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0

Keras: 2.3.1

CUDA: 10.1,

Cudnn: 7.6.5

Can anyone provide any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow 2.0 list\_physical\_devices doesn't detect my GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956619/tensorflow-2-0-list-physical-devices-doesnt-detect-my-gpu)

Comment: Thanks.
I tried this one with  pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0, because my code needs tf-gpu-2.1. But it didn't solve my problem.
And if I use 'XLA_GPU', then it's showing another error that it can not set the memory growth for non GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
else:
  print("No GPU device found")
```

If no gpu devices are getting detected, then upgrade your tensorflow, CUDA and CuDNN to latest and try. Since, there were some [bugs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30388) reported in the previous versions.

If you are using `XLA GPU` then refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla) document for info.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response