# tensorflow 2.8 list physical devices doesn't detect my gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have exactly the problem that described in:

[Tensorflow 2.0 list_physical_devices doesn't detect my GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956619/tensorflow-2-0-list-physical-devices-doesnt-detect-my-gpu)

I have tried the solution

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

But It didn't solved it, the test func:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(physical_devices)
if physical_devices:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

still gave empty list.

When I runed this pip3 command it said to me:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\lior\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages)
```

About 6 times. And also:

```
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

I am afraid to remove tensorflow and reinstall is with the GPU, as he recommended secondly. I think I will not be able to install it again. Do you recommend me to try it?

I asked google how to remove my temsorflow. It said me to erase the anconda folder by

```
rm -rf anaconda_folder
```

and now I can't import tensorflow becose it say to me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'saveable_objects_from_trackable' from 'tensorflow.python.training.saving.saveable_object_util' (C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py)
```

Another sagnificant remark is I was mistake my tf version, I have 2.8.0 and not 2.0:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\lior\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, tf-estimator-nightly, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by:
```

Comment: from tensorflow 2.0 you don't need to specify the -gpu portion. A simple pip install tensorflow should work.You should try to reinstall tensorflow, there is no reason as to why you wouldn't be able to do it

Comment: I asked google how to remove my temsorflow. It said me to erase the anconda folder by rm -rf anaconda_folder , and now I can't import tensorflow becose it say to me:  ImportError: cannot import name 'saveable_objects_from_trackable' from 'tensorflow.python.training.saving.saveable_object_util' (C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py)

Comment: Remove the folder? That isn't right, you should have ran a command to uninstall tensorflow. Obviously now python can't find tensorflow if you deleted it's folder, you need to run the command to install tensorflow again

Comment: Hi ! Work around is to install "conda install cudatoolkit" .                                           
I suggest you follow instructions in a new environment .  Attached relevant  document for reference.  https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip